# Switch root filesystem after copy

Tags: sysvinit, root-filesystem, u-boot

I currently have a script that copy the content of a microSD card to the eMMC of a BeagleBone Black. Once the copy is done, I would like to switch root filesystem for the eMMC and finish installing packages.

How can I switch root filesystem? I've found [switch_root](https://linux.die.net/man/8/switch_root) and [pivot_root](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root) commands, but no much example of how to use them.

My process would looks like this :

- Insert microSD card into BeagleBone Black
- Hold boot switch while applying power
- rc.local copy microSD to eMMC
- rc.local switch root filesystem from microSD to eMMC
- rc.local continues installing (now on eMMC)

OS used is SlackwareARM 14.1.

Note : the process could be called from somewhere else if possible, ie : earlier in init or from u-boot.